# Quadratic with missing Linear Coefficient

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, quadratics

> Let $x^2-mx+24$ be a quadratic with roots $x_1$ and $x_2$. If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are integers, how many different values of $m$ are possible?

I'm assuming we can use Vieta's Formula.

We can say $x_1+x_2=m,$ and $x_1\cdot x_2=24.$

$16$ values satisfy both of these conditions, so I think our solution would be $\boxed{16}.$ Did I go wrong somewhere in my process, or am I correct? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, but consider that the pairs $(3/8)$ and $(8/3)$ , for example, give the same sum. Now, you should be able to solve the problem.

Comment: In that case, we halve the solutions.

Comment: Exactly, you got it. It is also not difficult to write all pairs out and approve this result.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand now! :)

Answer (score 0):

$$24=2^33$$

So, the number of positive factors are $$(1+1)(3+1)$$ which will just be doubled if we permit negative factors

**See also** : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function

Comment: Does that double-count $(3,8)$ and $(8,3)$

Comment: @OscarLanzi,  $$(1,24);(2,12);(3:8):(4,6)$$  So, the maximum number of possible combinations could be $$\dfrac82$$